# Vertically align input when using Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How do I get the input box to be vertically aligned to the middle? I tried adding vertical-align: "middle" to a few places but I am not getting any success. I feel like flexbox is a part of the problem here?

```css
.container {
  /* Flex Properties */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  background-color: orange;
}

label {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <label>Gee my iefwaf fwats: </label>
    <input>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give the `.item` *div* `display: flex` and `align-items: center`, since it's the *parent* of the `input` *element*:

```css
.container {
  /* Flex Properties */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  display: flex; /* added */
  align-items: center; /* added */
  background-color: orange;
}

label {
  width: 100px;
  /*display: inline-block; not necessary*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <label>Gee my iefwaf fwats: </label>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this css code with your html.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

label {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
input {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check with the added CSS::

```css
.container {
  /* Flex Properties */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  background-color: orange;
}

    label {
      width: 100px;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }

input {
      width: 100px;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <label>Gee my iefwaf fwats: </label>
    <input>
  </div>
</div>
```